# Android studio random freezes after fresh install

Tags: java, android, freeze

I'm quite new to the Android Studio IDE however I simply cannot get it to work. After launching studio, it'll only take me interacting with the GUI to freeze the entire program, with the only way to close it being to end the process via task manager. I have no idea what the problem is, I have jdk 8 installed with the correct path and its a brand new installation (yes I've tried reinstalling). I've included my thread dumps if that helps:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Fi84lOZ2nIYk13dDBtMXB1akk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How long it freezes? I am not sure whether your "problem" same as mine, but mine freezing because gradle is synchronising and downloading missing component. Maybe you should wait for a while.

Comment: Im not sure about that, I left it alone for about an hour and was still frozen so im not sure.